# .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard) does not work on SwiftUI view

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have the following view which is presented as a `sheet`:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            VStack {
                TransactionAmount(amountString: $amountString)
                    .padding(.top, Constants.amountPadding)

                Spacer()

                SelectedCategory(selectedCategory: $selectedCategory)
                    .padding()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isCategoryPickerPresented = true
                        UIImpactFeedbackGenerator.feedback(style: .medium)
                    }

                AddTransactionToolbar(noteText: $noteText)
                    .padding(.horizontal)

                NumberPad(numberString: $amountString, selectedCategory: $selectedCategory)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isCategoryPickerPresented) {
                CategoryPicker(selection: $selectedCategory)
                    .presentationDetents([.medium])
            }
            .onAppear {
                selectedCategory = storageManager.categories.first
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
            .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
            .navigationTitle("Add Transaction")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason `ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)` is not working and my view is being pushed up when the keyboard is presented. Wrapping the view in `GeometryReader` hasn't made any difference either. Not really sure where to go from here. How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

**This way worked for me**

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            scrollView(height: reader.size.height)
        }.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
    } else {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            scrollView(height: reader.size.height)
        }
    }
```